# Category of all sheaves on all spaces and their (co)morphisms

Tags: ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

In Bredon's Sheaf Theory text, he defines a category of all sheaves on all spaces, whose arrows, called **cohomomorphisms**, are pairs $(\psi, f): \mathscr{F} \to \mathscr{E}$, where $\mathscr{E} \in \mathsf{Sh}(X)$, $\mathscr{F} \in \mathsf{Sh}(Y)$, $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous map, and $\psi: \mathscr{F} \to f_*\mathscr{E}$ is a sheaf homomorphism. These compose in the obvious way. I don't see comorphisms mentioned very often in sheaf theory texts, though they are used as the arrows in the category of ringed spaces.

However, we could just as well have defined our arrows to be pairs $(\theta, f): \mathscr{E} \to \mathscr{F}$ where $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous map, and $\theta: \mathscr{E} \to f^* \mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf homomorphism. This choice corresponds to the usual topological or differential-geometric definition of a bundle map, since a vector bundle map $E \to f^*F$ covering the identity on $X$ corresponds to a unique vector bundle map $E \to F$ covering $f:X \to Y$. The only disadvantage of this definition I can obviously see compared to the previous one is that $f^*$ is a left-adjoint, and rarely a right adjoint.

> 1. Is there a name for this second notion of morphism?
> 2. Are these sort of notions of morphisms of sheaves and the resulting categories of all sheaves on all spaces they define used often in algebraic geometry, sheaf theory and/or topos theory?
> 3. If so, is there a good reference that discusses the properties of the resulting categories of sheaves on all spaces?

Since algebraic geometers (I confess that I know very little algebraic geometry, and my sheaf theory is pretty rudimentary) seem to prefer to work with quasicoherent sheaves and locally free sheaves rather than dealing with vector bundles as spaces, I suspect that these notions of morphisms of sheaves would be commonly used.

Anyway, I apologize if this question is a bit vague. I am working in differential geometry, and my motivation for asking this question is that I am trying to correctly write down the correct "sheafified" versions of the definitions of a natural bundle functor and natural differential operator from [Natural Operations in Differential Geometry by Kolar, Michor, and Slovak](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf).

Comment: The first definition is essentially what leads to Isbell duality, which makes algebras antiequivalent to spaces. I suppose that it's natural to define a map of sections by precomposing with it with function between spaces, which is the first definition morally. I suppose that you've changed the definition of $\mathscr{E}$ and $\mathscr{F}$ in your second definition. In any case, even in the case of bundles this is not the correct map, it would just say that after composing with $f$, this would still be a bundle by universal property of the pullback.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but it seems to me that the second notion of arrows coincides with that of vector bundle maps. After all, a vector bundle map $E \to f^*F$ covering the identity on $X$ corresponds to a unique vector bundle homomorphism $E \to F$ covering $f: X \to Y$ by the universal property of the pullback.

Comment: Sorry. I see your point now, you're not talking about the étale space of a sheaf. Yes, this is true. This map is equivalent to the commuting square. But this morphism will not work for the structural sheaf of a space for instance. In your case, I suppose that it would be the sheaf of differentiable functions $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}_X$. Now, when you want to talk about sheaves of $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}_X$-modules, the morphism that one is interested is indeed your second one.

Comment: The first type of structure is abstractly studied as a Grothendieck opfibration, and the second as a Grothendieck fibration. There is quite a lot of general theory of fibered categories. In algebraic geometry, Vistoli has some notes including that phrase in the title.

Comment: Thanks! Are [these](http://homepage.sns.it/vistoli/descent.pdf) the notes you're thinking of?